# Fractional equalizer with non-integer oversampled signal as input

Tags: matlab, filtering, equalization

I would like to know how the output sequence from a fractionally spaced equalizer, with a non-integer oversampled input signal, is generated.

For example, for $T=T_{sym}/2$, my actual code is something like:

```
for ktime=1:2:L
    nindex                               = ktime+(Ntaps:-1:1);
    inputequalizer_block                 = inputsignal(nindex);
    outputequalizer(floor((ktime+1)/2))  = W*inputequalizer_block;   
end
```

Now, let's say I have an input signal with $T=2T_{sym}/3$. I understand I should have 2 different filters, but I dont know how the baudrate-output is generated:

```
 for ktime=1:3:L
    nindex                               = ktime+(Ntaps:-1:1);
    inputequalizer_block                 = inputsignal(nindex);
    for i=1:2
       output_aux(i)  = W{i}*inputequalizer_block;   
    end
    % Some processing on output_aux(1) and output_aux(2)?
    outputequalizer    =....
 end
```

I am not sure I am close to the solution, or miles and miles far away. 
Any suggestion?

Thanks